# render layout stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, render

Doing some integration work with another site I've got the unusual requirement of needing to create the layout at runtime.

At the moment I'm having to resort to something like this:

```
def new
  body = render_to_string 'new', :layout => false      
  page = add_layout(body, db.load_template)
  render :text => page
end
```

This is a bit awkward, I'd rather do something like:

```
def new
  ...
  render 'new', :layout => db.load_template
end
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Perhaps it's possible to register new layouts at runtime and use the normal syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ha! I encountered a project that will solve just that. Check out [panoramic](https://github.com/apeacox/panoramic). It stores rails views in the database instead of the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, the project doesn't do quite what I want but I had a look at the source to see how they were doing it. They register a subclass of ActionView::Resolver which lets you provide the template any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend ActionController::Base (or ApplicationController) with a module and alias_method_chain to make this work.

```
module Foo

  alias_method_chain :render, :dblayout

  def render_with_dblayout options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block
   if options.include? :dblayout
     ...
   else
     render_without_dblayout options, extra_options { yield }
   end
  end
end

ActionController::Base.send(:include, Foo)
```

Comment: can you please how can we use your implementation.